# Given a set $S =\{1,2,...,k\}$, how to generate variations of length $n, (k<n)$, such that each element of $S$ appears at least once?

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

Take, for example:
$$S=\{1,2,3\}\to k=3$$
$$n=4$$
The desired output for this would be:

```
[1 1 2 3]
[1 1 3 2]
[1 2 1 3]
[1 2 2 3]
[1 2 3 1]
[1 2 3 2]
[1 2 3 3]
[1 3 1 2]
[1 3 2 1]
[1 3 2 2]
[1 3 2 3]
[1 3 3 2]
[2 1 1 3]
[2 1 2 3]
[2 1 3 1]
[2 1 3 2]
[2 1 3 3]
[2 2 1 3]
[2 2 3 1]
[2 3 1 1]
[2 3 1 2]
[2 3 1 3]
[2 3 2 1]
[2 3 3 1]
[3 1 1 2]
[3 1 2 1]
[3 1 2 2]
[3 1 2 3]
[3 1 3 2]
[3 2 1 1]
[3 2 1 2]
[3 2 1 3]
[3 2 2 1]
[3 2 3 1]
[3 3 1 2]
[3 3 2 1]
```

I managed to generate this by iterating through every variation and eliminating those which are missing an element from $S$. However, I need a much more efficient algorithm, without recursive calls if possible. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run a recursive procedure which keeps track of which elements appeared so far. If there are $k$ elements which haven't appeared so far and only $k$ positions left, choose one of them.

With some care, you can convert the recursion to an iteration, if you so wish.